# Issues with expired passwords using XRDP in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, password, expired, xrdp

I am running a series of docker containers running an xfce desktop which can only be accessed via xrdp.  I set password restrictions and expired the current passwords of all users expecting to get a prompt through xrdp on the next login to change the password.

I would expect, once the user enters their (now expired) password they would be prompted to change the password and it would allow a login.  xrdp, however, simply fails with a "login failed for display 0".

Is there a setting I'm missing within xrdp that would allow for password reset / changes on login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is a known xrdp bug:

- https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/211
- https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/pull/600